# Horizontally merge 2 arrays

Tags: merge

I have 2 arrays as follows -

```
arr1 = [
    { name:"Subject1", lang:"English" },
    { name:"Subject2", lang:"French" }
]

arr2 = [
    { name:"Subject1", score:"100" },
    { name:"Subject3", score:"50" }
]
```

I would like to merge them horizontally to achieve the following result.

```
arr3 = [
    { name:"Subject1", lang:"English", score:"100" },
    { name:"Subject2", lang:"French" },
    { name:"Subject3", score:"50" }
]
```

Something like a full outer join in any rdbms.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

~ND

Looking at the other examples, it seems like a vertical merge is possible in multiple ways. For my requirement, I can manually loop thru the first array and add elements from the second array as necessary against matching rows but my arrays each have roughly 10,000 rows and about 6-10 columns.
Appreciate any help this forum can extend.